# Microsoft Outlook 'Calendar Sharing Service` benefits, drawbacks and alternatives?

Tags: exchange-2003, exchange-2010, calendar, outlook-2003, outlook-2010

I have users who want to share their calendar with external users.  What is the best way to approach this?

Outlook2003 has the Calendar Sharing Service, but I don't know if it's updated or replaced by something better in Exchange 2010 / Outlook 2010

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Exchange 2010 feature in SP1 that's great.  Called Internet Shared Calendars.  Your OWA servers can allow anonymous access to a sub-folder where you can access Calendars via webpage or .ics syncing.  Admin has policy control over what details are allowed and user can enable/disable their public calendar and a few other options.  Users get a button in Outlook 2010 Calendar View that takes them to the web page to change options.

Walkthough:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/ucedsg/archive/2010/09/02/how-do-i-enable-the-new-internet-calendar-sharing-ics-with-exchange-2010-sp1.aspx

FAQ 
http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2011/02/16/458128.aspx